# wso2am log mediator Suspends API

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-api-manager, mediator

I am using a custom log mediator to construct a log message. 
The mediators i use are the following

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WSO2AM--Ext--In">
        <property name="client" expression="get-property('axis2', 'REMOTE_ADDR')"/>
        <property name="parentID" expression="synapse:get-property('MessageID')"/>
        <property name="AuthHeader" expression="$trp:Authorization"/>

    <log level="full">
    <property name="AuthHeader:" expression="$trp:Authorization"/>
        <property name="ActualRemoteAddress:" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"/>
    </log>
</sequence>


<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WSO2AM--Ext--Out">
    <log level="full">
        <property name="ParentID:" expression="get-property('parentID')"/>
        <property name="ActualRemoteAddress:" expression="get-property('client')"/>
        <property name="AuthHeader:" expression="get-property('AuthHeader')"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

After running 200 requests at the API, the api gets SUSPENDED.
Is there a way to avoid that? (Why is it happening)

In case i don't use the mediators, or use a log level="headers" the api does not get suspended.
The stack-trace in the wso2carbon.log file is the following

```
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-28 16:40:49,233]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  http-outgoing-37: Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-28 16:40:49,237]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-203 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-28 16:40:49,246]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Endpoint : admin--InsertIncident_APIproductionEndpoint_0 will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-28 16:40:49,247]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Suspending endpoint : admin--InsertIncident_APIproductionEndpoint_0 - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Mon Nov 28 16:41:19 EET 2016 {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-28 16:40:49,247]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101507, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in Sender {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-28 16:40:49,259] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} -  Failed to submit the response {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.SourceResponseFactory.create(SourceResponseFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:462)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:267)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:493)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.invokeNextFaultHandler(AbstractEndpoint.java:680)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.onFault(AbstractEndpoint.java:515)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.onFault(HTTPEndpoint.java:66)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:259)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetErrorHandler$1.run(TargetErrorHandler.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-28 16:40:49,265] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*,Expect:100-continue,SOAPAction:InsertIncident,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode xmlns:axis2ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">axis2ns1:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Error in Sender</faultstring></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:610)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:493)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.invokeNextFaultHandler(AbstractEndpoint.java:680)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.onFault(AbstractEndpoint.java:515)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.onFault(HTTPEndpoint.java:66)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:259)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetErrorHandler$1.run(TargetErrorHandler.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.SourceResponseFactory.create(SourceResponseFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:462)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:267)
    ... 20 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-28 16:40:49,270]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101507, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in Sender {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-28 16:40:49,276] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} -  Failed to submit the response {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.SourceResponseFactory.create(SourceResponseFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:462)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:267)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:493)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:60)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.invokeNextFaultHandler(AbstractEndpoint.java:680)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.onFault(AbstractEndpoint.java:515)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.onFault(HTTPEndpoint.java:66)
    at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:259)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetErrorHandler$1.run(TargetErrorHandler.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here are the wire logs.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ket2mgn1d9kf3we/wso2carbon.log

They contain the last request-response that got through and the one that suspends the api.

(bear in mind that both the wso2am and wso2as lie on the same virtual machine)

Comment: Please try with log level="custom"

Comment: Changing the log level to custom makes the problem dissapear but the fact is that i need the log level=full in order to get the whole message

Comment: looks like a response building issue. please enable wire logs and post logs. http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Comment: What i see in the attach wire log is your backend not returing any response ,thus endpoints is getting suspended. You can analyse the incoming and outgoing messages as described in this blog

http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html